# Generic methods for primitive types in java

Tags: java, generics, primitive

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class Size 
{
    public static int size(Iterable<?> data) 
    {
        if (data instanceof Collection) {
            return ((Collection<?>) data).size();
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (Object i : data) {
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static int size(int[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(double[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(float[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(short[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(boolean[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(char[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static <T> int size(T[] data) 
    {
        return data.length;
    }
}
```

The `size` method is the same for all primitive arrays. Is there a way to avoid this redundancy?

Comment: Is this a question about using primitive types as generics or about a generalized way to find the length of a primitive array?

Comment: It's about using primitive types as generics.

Comment: As for your specific example, `public static int size (Object o) { return java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(o); }` can be used as a replacement for your array cases. It's almost equivalent overall behavior to your example except `size(...)` will now accept any type and thrown an `IllegalArgumentException` at run-time, rather than a compile-time error on unimplemented types.

Comment: Does this have any drawbacks performance-wise?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could measure it. However, I guarantee your performance bottleneck, if any, will not be in determining the size of the array. Anything else you are doing will dwarf this by a large factor.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. That's the price of working with primitives.

You can see examples of this unavoidable redundancy in many methods in the `java.util.Arrays` class, where each kind of primitive array has a different method (examples : copyOf, sort, swap, etc...).

Comment: Addendum: In the OP's specific example case, `Array.getLength()` can be used on any array type (parameter is `Object`, length is determined via reflection).